# How to mock CompletableFuture.get() to throw an exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

i have code as below

```
public Object getStatus(CompletableFuture<Object> futureA, CompletableFuture<Object> futureB) {
CompletableFuture.allOf(futureA, futureB).join();
try {
if(futureA.get()!=null) return futureA.get();
} catch(SomeException e) {
//log
}
try {
if(futureB.get()!=null) return futureB.get();
} catch(SomeException e) {
//log
}
}
```

i have my test as below

```
@Test
public void testException() {
CompletableFuture<Object> futureA = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<Object> futureB = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
CompletableFuture<Object> spy = Mockito.spy(futureA);
when(spy.get()).thenThrow(new SomeException());
service.getStatus(futureA, futureB);
}
```

trying to cover the catch block, but this is not working, it is waiting for futureA to complete. how do i test the catch block?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use what the API offer:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> failed = new CompletableFuture<>();
failed.completeExceptionally(new SomeException());
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-):

> If not already completed, causes invocations of get() and related methods to throw the given exception.

However, `get()` will raise `ExecutionException` and the cause should be `SomeException`, which means your `getStatus` code is not valid:

```
try {
  return futureA.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // handle cause, eg: if (e.getCause() instanceof SomeException) ...
}
try {
  return futureB.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // handle cause, eg: if (e.getCause() instanceof SomeException) ...
}
return null; // or whatever default value/exception
```

Comment: or `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { throw new SomeException(); })` (if it's an unchecked exception, that is)

Comment: @nodatafound 
this doesn't work
CompletableFuture<Object> failed = new CompletableFuture<>();
failed.completeExceptionally(new SomeException());
because documentation says, if not completed, but we're calling failed.completeExceptionally that makes it to complete with exception and control is not reaching futureA.get() call in try block.

Comment: You should check the code of CompletableFuture: I'm pretty sure the only exception you get there are the checked one InterruptedException, CancellationException (or so) and ExecutionException. I don't think a runtime exception will be send "as is": you would have ExecutionException even in this case